# Dependency troubles on RHEL7 snmp/mariaDB

Tags: mysql, redhat, snmp, mariadb

I have installed net-snmp on a lot of my servers but I have trouble with my mariaDB servers : I can't install net-snmp due to mysql dependencies.

```
  [root@XXXXXXX:~]# yum install net-snmp
  Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, rhnplugin
  This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
  Determining fastest mirrors
  centos7-x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                        | 1.3 kB  00:00:00     
  centos7-x86_64/group                                                                                                                                                                                                  | 1.8 kB  00:00:00     
  centos7-x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                                                                                                                             | 1.3 MB  00:00:00     
  centos7-x86_64/primary                                                                                                                                                                                                | 9.3 MB  00:00:00     
  centos7-x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                   25981/25981
  epel_centos7                                                                                                                                                                                                          | 1.3 kB  00:00:00     
  epel_centos7/group                                                                                                                                                                                                    | 1.3 MB  00:00:00     
  epel_centos7/updateinfo                                                                                                                                                                                               | 800 kB  00:00:00     
  epel_centos7/primary                                                                                                                                                                                                  | 3.6 MB  00:00:00     
  epel_centos7                                                                                                                                                                                                                     10133/10133
  puppetlabs_centos7                                                                                                                                                                                                    |  871 B  00:00:00     
  puppetlabs_centos7/primary                                                                                                                                                                                            |  45 kB  00:00:00     
  puppetlabs_centos7                                                                                                                                                                                                                   213/213
  spacewalk-client_centos7                                                                                                                                                                                              | 1.0 kB  00:00:00     
  spacewalk-client_centos7/group                                                                                                                                                                                        | 1.8 kB  00:00:00     
  spacewalk-client_centos7/primary                                                                                                                                                                                      | 6.3 kB  00:00:00     
  spacewalk-client_centos7                                                                                                                                                                                                               23/23
  Resolving Dependencies
  --> Running transaction check
  ---> Package net-snmp.x86_64 1:5.7.2-24.el7 will be installed
  --> Processing Dependency: net-snmp-agent-libs = 1:5.7.2-24.el7 for package: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-24.el7.x86_64
  --> Processing Dependency: mysql-libs for package: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-24.el7.x86_64
  --> Processing Dependency: libnetsnmptrapd.so.31()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-24.el7.x86_64
  --> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-24.el7.x86_64
  --> Processing Dependency: libnetsnmpmibs.so.31()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-24.el7.x86_64
  --> Processing Dependency: libnetsnmpagent.so.31()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-24.el7.x86_64
  --> Running transaction check
  ---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.7.18-1.el7 will be installed
  --> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) >= 5.7.9 for package: mysql-community-libs-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64
  ---> Package mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64 0:5.7.18-1.el7 will be installed
  ---> Package net-snmp-agent-libs.x86_64 1:5.7.2-24.el7 will be installed
  --> Running transaction check
  ---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.7.18-1.el7 will be installed
  --> Finished Dependency Resolution

  Dependencies Resolved

  =============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
   Package                                                              Arch                                            Version                                                  Repository                                               Size
  =============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
  Installing:
   net-snmp                                                             x86_64                                          1:5.7.2-24.el7                                           centos7-x86_64                                          321 k
  Installing for dependencies:
   mysql-community-common                                               x86_64                                          5.7.18-1.el7                                             centos7-x86_64                                          271 k
   mysql-community-libs                                                 x86_64                                          5.7.18-1.el7                                             centos7-x86_64                                          2.1 M
   mysql-community-libs-compat                                          x86_64                                          5.7.18-1.el7                                             centos7-x86_64                                          2.0 M
   net-snmp-agent-libs                                                  x86_64                                          1:5.7.2-24.el7                                           centos7-x86_64                                          702 k

  Transaction Summary
  =============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
  Install  1 Package (+4 Dependent packages)

  Total download size: 5.4 M
  Installed size: 24 M
  Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
  Downloading packages:
  (1/5): mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                 | 271 kB  00:00:00     
  (2/5): mysql-community-libs-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                   | 2.1 MB  00:00:00     
  (3/5): mysql-community-libs-compat-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                            | 2.0 MB  00:00:00     
  (4/5): net-snmp-5.7.2-24.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                               | 321 kB  00:00:00     
  (5/5): net-snmp-agent-libs-5.7.2-24.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                    | 702 kB  00:00:00     
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Total                                                                                                                                                                                                        5.7 MB/s | 5.4 MB  00:00:00     
  Running transaction check
  Running transaction test


  Transaction check error:
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/armscii8.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ascii.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1256.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1257.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp850.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp852.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp866.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/dec8.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/geostd8.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/greek.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hebrew.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hp8.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/keybcs2.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8r.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8u.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin1.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin2.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin5.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin7.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macce.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macroman.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/swe7.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
    file /usr/share/mysql/errmsg-utf8.txt from install of mysql-community-common-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64

  Error Summary
  -------------
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by updating mariadb-common (it was version 10.1.20 and now 10.1.22)